# Shortcut key to delete single mail in a conversation in Gmail

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

When I send mail to all contacts in my list (that's a huge number), I get a lot of failure notices that fills my thread. But I don't want to delete my actual sent email and the one I forwarded which is in same thread.

So currently what I have to do is, for all the number of failures, `Expand All > Options > Delete this message`. This is very tedious.

**Not answers for me:**

- I know I can filter them, but then many other times I need to see that my email is properly delivered.
- Don't want to create filter using subject of the email every time I send email to all all my contacts.
- Also I know that if nothing works, I will have to remove the contacts from my contact list to which sending email fails more often.

(<kbd>#</kbd> key can be used as a shortcut key to delete whole conversation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to delete a single mail using your keyboard.

Comment: `#` is the shortcut to delete a conversation.

Comment: No keyboard shortcut exists to delete a single message. (Gmail seems wired to try and keep people from thinking of anything but "conversations".)

Comment: Yeah it's pretty aggravating. My use case is I have these reminder emails - that spam up a conversation. I like to quickly delete them, and so a keyboard shortcut would make life easier

Comment: I'm hoping someone could make a Chrome extension to do this.

Comment: It's very painful to not have such a hotkey.